# Typescript não possibilitando o uso da propriedade files

Tags: javascript, html, ionic, typescript, ionic2

Estou com um problema em ionic, em que eu uso a propriedade `.files` em um id de um elemento `<input type="file">`, dessa maneira:

```
<input type="file" id="images" multiple>
this.register.images = document.getElementById('images').files;
```

E ele funciona, o `this.register.images` é populado com os arquivos enviados no `input` porém, o Editor de texto que uso (Visual Studio Code) aponta o seguinte erro: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que por sua vez, quando faço a build do ionic, ele me gera um erro na compilação:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E sendo assim, não consigo continuar com o desenvolvimento do aplicativo, portanto:

- Existe alguma maneira para que esse erro suma?
- Ou alguma outra maneira de pegar os `files` de um `<input type="file">`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não é um erro, o que ocorre é que o método `document.getElementById` retorna uma algo do tipo `HTMLElement | null`, sendo assim voce tem que verificar a instancia do seu elemento.

```
let element: HTMLElement | null = document.getElementById('images');
if ( element instanceof HTMLInputElement ) {
    this.register.images = element.files
}
```

Isso ocorre pois o TypeScript não tem como saber o tipo de elemento que estárá presente no DOM, sendo assim ele retorna a interface que atende a necessidade de qualquer elemento( span, div, p, etc...)